R3F animate from intermediate uv state
In a react-three-fiber environment, how do I animate a point model starting from some intermediate state?
The specific problem I'm trying to solve is, I have an animation that moves between some initial and some final position by controlling a "progress" uniform in the vertex shader via simple GSAP animation:
// vert.js
export const vertex = /* glsl */ `
uniform float uProgress;
attribute vec3 initPosition;

void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(initPosition + (position - initPosition) * uProgress, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

}`

and then
// Material.js
export function Material({ texture }) {
    const materialRef = useRef();

    useGSAP(() => {
        gsap.fromTo(materialRef.current.uniforms.uProgress,
            {
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                value: 1,
                duration: 15,
                ease: 'power4.out'
            }
        )
    });

    return (
        <shaderMaterial
            ref={materialRef}
            vertexShader={vertexShader}
            fragmentShader={fragmentShader}
            uniforms={{
                uProgress: { value: 0 },
                uTexture: { value: texture }
            }}
            transparent
            depthTest={false}
            depthWrite={false}
        />
    );
}


I now want to extend this, so there are multiple animations moving to different textures based on some event (specifically, this is NextJS, and the target will change based on route change).
This discussion from the ThreeJS Discourse suggests to use an array of textures and loop through them with GSAP (pure ThreeJS example still live on Codepen).
That seems like a great start, and I could pretty easily adapt it to my current state of affairs. The problem is, how do you handle the situation where the event fires in the middle of an animation?
The gl_Position is happily moving along as uProgress 0->1. The event fires, and what I would like to have happen is all of my particles stop their journey to the current destination, and start moving from where they currently are to the new destination. I can't just swap out the array indexes as in the example, because then all of the particles will jump to some new position before resuming their journey.
Any idea how to solve this? It feels like I need to do something with state and the uv coordinates, but I can't find any examples of that.
NB: I'm not tied to GSAP, so if I need to do something with a different library like Spring, or even do something manually with R3F's useFrame, I'm OK with that. I just can't find any examples where you modify uv state starting from some intermediate position.
